# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleShardingKeyBuilder

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to get DB connection from DB pool. Following is my source code and it returns " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleShardingKeyBuilder" at runtime. But I have imported ucp.jar file.

Please help me to sort out the issue.

```
private static PoolDataSource pds = null;
private static Connection conn = null;

public static synchronized Connection getConnectionFromPool() throws Exception {
    String print;
    String nl = "\r\n";
    try {
        pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        System.out.println(CommonInfo.url);
        System.out.println(CommonInfo.uName);
        pds.setURL(CommonInfo.url);
        pds.setUser(CommonInfo.uName);
        pds.setPassword(CommonInfo.uPassword);
        pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");

        //Setting pool properties
        pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(20);

        int usedConnctionCount = pds.getBorrowedConnectionsCount();
        int AvailableConnctionCount = pds.getAvailableConnectionsCount();

        int totalCount = usedConnctionCount + AvailableConnctionCount;


        if (AvailableConnctionCount != 0) {

            conn = pds.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

            usedConnctionCount = pds.getBorrowedConnectionsCount();
            AvailableConnctionCount = pds.getAvailableConnectionsCount();

            totalCount = usedConnctionCount + AvailableConnctionCount;


            return conn;
        } else {
            print = "All connections in the database pool are now busy...";
            System.out.println(print);
            throw new Exception("All connections in the database pool are now busy.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleShardingKeyBuilder
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource(PoolDataSourceFactory.java:48)
```

Comment: What version jar have you imported??

Comment: I have downloaded Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4) UCP Download from oracle site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the driver jar file. You need to download the right version of jar and place it in the `classpath` . Here is from oracle docs on the support:

Prior to 12c (i.e., 12.1.0.1.0), UCP could work with any version of Oracle JDBC driver. With the new pool, UCP 12.1.0.2, it is dependent on Oracle JDBC driver 12.1.0.2. Example: 12.2.0.1 ucp.jar requires ojdbc8.jar from 12.2.0.1.  Oracle recommendation is to keep both ucp.jar and JDBC drivers from the same version.

Comment: Actually instead of a recommendation from Oracle it should be a requirement that both the driver's jar and the ucp's jar are on the same version.